# Python - ssh to remote host and open a file and work on that particular file

Tags: python-3.x, file, ssh

I need to ssh to a remote host
Open a yaml file
Search and replace a string within that file and save it

Need some pointers around the same.

```
import paramiko
import json
import re

ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())

ssh.connect('0.0.0.0', username='user', password='<password>', key_filename='qa.pem')

stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command('cat /opt/application/netapp/cloudmanager/sbt/bin/docker-compose.yaml')

yml = stdout.read().decode()

### Regex - Look behind and look ahead 
regEx = re.compile(r'(?<=cloudmanagerinfra.XXX.io/cloudmanager_XXX:development-).*(?=")')
fetch = str(regEx.findall(yml))
print(fetch.strip('[]'))
print(fetch.replace(fetch,replace))

ssh.close()
```

---

In my approach, I could not open the file for edit
When I try to open the file, I get and error message, - File not found
Apparently, I am able to cat to the same file and extract information

Need pointers on how to open a file for edit and save the same